# Tabular content spilling over right column margin

Tags: tables, margins

`tabular` content spilling over right column margin.  What's going on here?  How can I fix it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\author{Peter Cao}
\date{}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption} %apparently needs to come first or options clash with other packages will occur

\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames]{xcolor} %for use in color links



\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Blue4,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %for > and < in text mode
\usepackage{tikz}
\mhchemoptions{arrows=pgf-filled}

\usepackage{booktabs} %for top, middle and bottomline

\usepackage{multirow} %multi column and row spanning

\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}




\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{fancyheadings} seems to be obsoleted by fancyhdr

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multicol}


\usepackage{lastpage}

\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{} %a null macro which gobbles up comments, and thus acts as a tool for in-line commenting.


\usepackage{blindtext}




\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\subsection*{Results}

{\small
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l | c | c}
\toprule
Characteristic & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Result}\\
 \cmidrule(l){2-3}
 & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-3}
Cell shape & Rod & Rod\\
Gram stain & $-$ & $-$\\
Oxidase & $+$ & $-$\\
Catalase & $+$ & $-$\\
MSA & Growth & No growth\\
Anaerobic & Growth (weak) & No growth\\
Motility & & \\
Indole production & & \\
Hugh \& Leifsons & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}

\blindtext

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

**Updated version demonstrating shrinkage issues:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} %for top, middle and bottomline
\usepackage{multirow} %multi column and row spanning
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\subsection*{Results}


{\noindent
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c c @{}}
\toprule
Characteristic & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Result}\\
 \cmidrule{2-3}
 & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
 \midrule
Cell shape & Rod & Rod\\
Gram stain & $-$ & $-$\\
Oxidase & $+$ & $-$\\
Catalase & $+$ & $-$\\
Anaerobic & Growth (weak) & No growth\\
Motility & & \\
Indole production & & \\
Hugh \& Leifsons & & \\
MSA & Growth & No growth\\
Growth in absence of salt & & \\
Colony pigmentation & White & White \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
}



\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I already showed you in the other examples what to do ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\date{}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption} %apparently needs to come first or options clash with other packages will occur

\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames]{xcolor} %for use in color links
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Blue4,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %for > and < in text mode
\usepackage{tikz}
\mhchemoptions{arrows=pgf-filled}

\usepackage{booktabs} %for top, middle and bottomline

\usepackage{multirow} %multi column and row spanning

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{fancyheadings} seems to be obsoleted by fancyhdr
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{} %a null macro which gobbles up comments, and thus acts as a tool for in-line commenting.
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\subsection*{Results}

\noindent
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} l | c | c @{}}
\toprule
Characteristic & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Result}\\
 \cmidrule(l){2-3}
 & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-3}
Cell shape & Rod & Rod\\
Gram stain & $-$ & $-$\\
Oxidase & $+$ & $-$\\
Catalase & $+$ & $-$\\
MSA & Growth & No growth\\
Anaerobic & Growth (weak) & No growth\\
Motility & & \\
Indole production & & \\
Hugh \& Leifsons & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}

\bigskip
\blindtext

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

it is also possible to fiddle with a surrounding `tabularx` or a `\parshape` to get "unbalanced" columns:

[image]

Comment: Would resizing the table to the column width not be the last resort, due to the resulting odd font size? (Ok, I often do this by myself, but thought it is a bad habit)

Comment: My table text became tiny as I added new rows to it.  Resizebox was great until it became so small I could barely make out the content...is there another way to achieve the same effect without resizebox shrinking my font?  A little bit of shrinking is ok, but anything less than size 8pt becomes non-legible...

Comment: @ptrcao: It maybe a good idea if you could provide a complete example of your table, then we do not need to show you solutions which cannot work ...

Comment: Of course - see OP under the heading "Updated version demonstrating shrinkage issues".  This is where I'm at now, and as you can see, resizebox is great until a certain point when things become a bit difficult to read due to smallness of the font...

Comment: @ptrcao: if you can split the text into paragraphs then you can use two multiols or a tabularx for the table and text, see image in the edited answer

Comment: Ah, I see, that is clever; only one problem - I would do that if I were writing the article for myself; but alas scientific articles are by convention split into two balanced columns and no journal would allow me to break with this convention.  It is ok if lines of text in the left column are broken if they're too long, just as long as hyphenation is prevented, we could make it work that way perhaps?

Comment: Another possibility is to revert to single column, just for the table's sake, and then to resume multicolumn immediately after the table...  That would be acceptable by science conventions I think.  But our table isn't terribly wide and it seems we might just be able to reformat it to fit the column, so perhaps this could be left as a last resort...

Comment: then use two multicols and put the tabular horizontally centered between them.

Comment: If I did opt to have the left column fixed and allow for line breaking, I would have to find a way to indent the spill-over lines of text for each row that is broken, so they appear subordinate to the first line.

Answer (score 6):

The `tabularx` environment can only adjust the widths of table columns with the `X` specifier. To allow it to adjust a centred column you need to replace the column specifier `c` with

```
>{\centering\arraybackslash}X
```

For a left aligned column, use

```
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
```

So, a simple example would look like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}
{ | l | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash} X | >{\centering\arraybackslash} X | }
Leave this column alone. & Left justify and adjust this column. &
Centre and adjust this column. \\ 
\end{tabularx}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Have a look at section 4.2 of the [tabularx package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf) for more details.

Comment: In your case you can get there by adjusting the first column only to an "X" column, and specifying hyphenation for "Characteristic". But it looks pretty terrible, because there end up being odd word breaks. You can only squeeze so much into narrow columns, so it's crucial prune the text itself as far as possible!